# Split last dimension of arrays in lower dimensional arrays

Tags: numpy, split

Assume we have an array with `NxMxD` shape. I want to get a list with `D` `NxM` arrays.

The correct way of doing it would be:

```
np.dsplit(myarray, D)
```

However, this returns `D` `NxMx1` arrays.

I can achieve the desired result by doing something like:

```
[myarray[..., i] for i in range(D)]
```

Or:

```
[np.squeeze(subarray) for subarray in np.dsplit(myarray, D)]
```

However, I feel like it is a bit redundant to need to perform an additional operation. Am I missing any `numpy` function that returns the desired result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `D.swapaxes(1,2).swapaxes(1,0)`

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>a = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
>>>a
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])

>>>[a[:,:,i] for i in range(4)]
[array([[ 0,  4,  8],
       [12, 16, 20]]),
 array([[ 1,  5,  9],
       [13, 17, 21]]),
 array([[ 2,  6, 10],
       [14, 18, 22]]),
 array([[ 3,  7, 11],
       [15, 19, 23]])]

>>>a.swapaxes(1,2).swapaxes(1,0)
array([[[ 0,  4,  8],
        [12, 16, 20]],

       [[ 1,  5,  9],
        [13, 17, 21]],

       [[ 2,  6, 10],
        [14, 18, 22]],

       [[ 3,  7, 11],
        [15, 19, 23]]])
```

Edit: As pointed out by ajcr (thanks again), the `transpose` command is more convenient since the two swaps can be done in one step by using

```
D.transpose(2,0,1)
```

Comment: Instead of `a.swapaxes(1,2).swapaxes(1,0)` you could also write `a.transpose(2,0,1)`.

Comment: @ajcr: thanks! I suspected that something like `tranpose` must exist but I didn't know it

Answer (score 2):

`np.dsplit` uses `np.array_split`, the core of which is:

```
sub_arys = []
sary = _nx.swapaxes(ary, axis, 0)
for i in range(Nsections):
    st = div_points[i]; end = div_points[i+1]
    sub_arys.append(_nx.swapaxes(sary[st:end], axis, 0))
```

with `axis=-1`, this is equivalent to:

```
[x[...,i:(i+1)] for i in np.arange(x.shape[-1])]  # or
[x[...,[i]] for i in np.arange(x.shape[-1])]
```

which accounts for the singleton dimension.

So there's nothing wrong or inefficient about your

```
[x[...,i] for i in np.arange(x.shape[-1])]
```

Actually in quick time tests, any use of `dsplit` is slow.  It's generality costs.  So adding `squeeze` is relatively cheap.

But by accepting the other answer, it looks like you are really looking for an array of the correct shape, rather than a list of arrays.  For many operations that makes sense.  `split` is more useful when the subarrays have more than one 'row' along the split axis, or even an uneven number of 'rows'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes more sense now, and is nice to know that the list comprehension is not inefficient. However, as you pointed out, for most of the cases the transpose operator makes sense, and in my case, the number and size of dimensions is constant and always known. Using transpose I can do things like `a, b, c, d = np.transpose(m, (2,0,1))`. That's why I accepted the answer.

Comment: `transpose` or `swapaxes` is often used in `numpy` functions to move the desired action `axis` to the front or back of the list.   It's easier to write the rest of the action this way.  `np.tensordot` is a good example.